# IE -10 -Ajax get method not hitting Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular-directive

```
$http({
method: 'GET',

dataType: 'json',

url: 'Calendar/GetDate',

params: { calenderId: $scope.CalendarId, fyYear: new Date(viewValue).toUTCString() 

}
}).success(function (result) {

alert(result);

});
```

---

Below value getting returns, and its not calling the controller method

---

```
[UMAuthorize]
public ActionResult GetDate(string calenderId, DateTime fyYear)
{
 ....... 
 .....
return Json(new { startDate }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are posting data to controller so I guess you should put the attribute HttpPost as shown below :-

```
[UMAuthorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetDate(string calenderId, DateTime fyYear)
{
 ....... 
 .....
return Json(new { startDate }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and from you are calling controller make it a Post method instead of Get as shown below :-

```
$http({
method: 'POST',

dataType: 'json',

url: 'Calendar/GetDate',

params: { calenderId: $scope.CalendarId, fyYear: new Date(viewValue)

}
}).success(function (result) {

alert(result);

});
```

and ur `fyYear` object is DateTime in controller but you are converting it into string and then sending so its not matching the parameters of controller

Answer (score 0):

I susupect the the url passed is wrong, use `Url.Action()` helper for generating correct url:

change:

```
url: 'Calendar/GetDate'
```

to:

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetDate","Calendar")'
```